# Error handling for AWS CLI in bash script for duplicate security group

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am creating a security group using AWS CLI using Bash script. I want to implement an error handling in the script for example if I create a security group with the same name I can handle it with if-else or any other iteration.

```
read -p "Enter the Security group name :" group_name
read -p "Enter the Security group description :" description
sgGroup_id=$(aws ec2 create-security-group --group-name $group_name --description "$description" --vpc-id vpc-547eae32 --output json | sed 's/}//g;s/"//g;s/ //g;s/{//g;s/GroupId://g')

while [ "$?" -eq "255" ]; do
echo "Dublicate name, enter detials again"
    read -p "Enter the Security group name :" group_name
    read -p "Enter the Security group description :" description
    sgGroup_id=$(aws ec2 create-security-group --group-name $group_name --description "$description" --vpc-id vpc-547eae32 --output json | sed 's/}//g;s/"//g;s/ //g;s/{//g;s/GroupId://g')
done
```

But this is not working for me. 
this is the error code that comes for duplicate sg creation.

`An error occurred (InvalidGroup.Duplicate) when calling the CreateSecurityGroup operation: The security group 'testsg1w' already exists for VPC 'vpc-547eae32`'

Please tell me how can I handle this error.

Comment: Presumably you are losing the 255 exit code because you are piping the output of the awscli through sed. Try simply capturing the output of the awscli (without the sed pipeline), then test $?, and then if $? is 0 you can perform sed to retrieve the group ID.

Comment: I tried without sed, its a same issue.

Comment: Works for me. It writes the error text to stderr (which you are not capturing, which is why it prints to the terminal) and if I test $? it is indeed equal to 255 and the script outputs "Dublicate [sic] name, enter detials [sic] again" and prompts me to re-enter the group name. If you want to hide the error message, then simply redirect stderr to stdout by appending 2>&1, like so: sgGroup_id=$(aws ec2 create-security-group --group-name $group_name --description "$description" --vpc-id vpc-547eae32 2>&1)

Comment: Thanks Jarmod, this works for me but I want to capture a specific error for this for instance duplicate name in this case.  Exit code 255 is for all error in CLI, do you know how can I achieve that. `InvalidGroup.Duplicate`

Comment: isn't there some cmd that you could run before the `-create`, like `aws ec2 query-security-group --group-name $group_name ...` (or others `list-security-group`, etc, etc). Not an `aws` person, obiviously, just a 2nd set of eyes to your problem. Good luck!

Comment: You *could* grep the returned text for InvalidGroup.Duplicate but that's a really bad way to do this. Instead, you should probably abandon the awscli here and instead write your script using the Python SDK (boto3) or Node.js SDK. Should be simple to write, and would give you all the flexibility that you need to check the results of your API calls.

Comment: Hi Jarmod, I am still getting the error message popped up here is the code that I am running. >>

`aws ec2 create-security-group --group-name $group_name --description "$description" --vpc-id vpc-547eae32 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for this by myself,
What I did is compared the name given by the user with the already existing name in AWS.
If the name already existed them asked for a different name.

```
read -p "Enter the Security group name :" group_name
    STR=`aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=vpc-id,Values=$vpcId --query 'SecurityGroups[*].GroupName' --output text`
    echo $STR | grep $group_name &> /dev/nul
    while [ $? == 0 ]; 
    do
    echo ""
    echo "A security-group already exists by this name, please try a different name"
    echo ""
    read -p "Enter the Security group name :" group_name
    STR=`aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=vpc-id,Values=$vpcId --query 'SecurityGroups[*].GroupName' --output text`
    echo $STR | grep $group_name &> /dev/nul
    if [ $? == 0 ]; then
        echo ""
        echo "A security-group already exists by this name, please try a different name"
        continue
    else    
        break
    fi
    done
    read -p "Enter the Security group description :" description
    aws ec2 create-security-group --group-name $group_name --description "$description" --vpc-id $vpcId
```

Comment: Using &> /dev/nul is problematic in a number of ways. I'm guessing you meant to use > /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: Your shell script is bugged. It will fail if you are trying to create a security group named "ssh" when there is already an existing security group named "sshgroup" or 'myssh' because 'ssh' is a substring of both.

Comment: How do I overcome this then?

Comment: Your variant of grep may have an exact word match option (it's typically -w). The better option here, in my opinion, is to write your script in Python or JavaScript, using the AWS SDK in which case you simply invoke the relevant 'create security group' API and deal with exceptions (including when the security group already exists).